# Plot fails with pgfplots and TikZ after updating to Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

When I compile with TeXShop the following code the axes are correctly drawn but the plot fails to appear.

```
    %!TEX TS-options = --shell-escape 
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
    \tikzset{gnuplot def/.style={samples=100,id=\arabic{idGnuplot},prefix=\jobname }}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$,  ylabel=$\sin(x)$ ] 
           \addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

'''

I am getting the following error in the log file  when I compile with TeXShop.

« This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.3.18)  20 MAR 2020 18:55
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**courbes.tex
(./courbes.tex

…..
 /…..

\openout3 = `courbes.sin.gnuplot'.

runsystem(gnuplot courbes.sin.gnuplot)...executed.

./courbes.tex:14: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'courb
es.sin.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape fea
ture? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>

gnuplot .gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.14        \addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};

….

What do I ned to fix this error

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Seems a bit like it no longer finds `gnuplot`. What do you get if you type `which gnuplot` on the console? Maybe you can try reinstalling it.

Comment: If you installed a system of Unix packages like Mac ports or home brew, you need to reinstall that every time you upgrade the OS.

Comment: Gnuplot works fine. The problem seems to be that the system can not write the file courbes.sin.table